# Bottom cabinet and top questions

Tags: kitchen-counters, countertops

I want a deeper countertop than I currently have so I want to pull the lower cabinets away from the wall and re-anchor them. Then top off with a deeper new countertop. I already plan to purchase a new sink for this. Does anyone see any potential problems with this?

Comment: Make sure you can get a deeper counter top without paying an arm and leg for it.  Custom jobs can cost.  For the cabinets just need to slap some 2x4s or thick enough wood to the walls for anchoring.  Drain pipe for the sink might need adjustment.  Depending on counter top material might need a 2x4 under the back of the top for support.

Comment: Depending on how professional you want it to look, you should extend your hot an cold supply lines and shutoff valves to your "new" cabint back and also relocate any electrical oulets for disposal and dishwasher if they are there.  Deepening the countertop could also affect you or a significant other from reaching the cabinets above the countertop.

Comment: If your selling timeframe is short-ish, be aware that a strange counter configuration might not be as attractive to a future buyer. My planned timeframe would have to be >10 years before sale, but that's partly b/c I don't see as much upside to deep counters.

Comment: @HHouse are you using the existing cabinets for this?  If so, you may need to cut or box out the back of your sink cabinet, unless you're offsetting your faucet the same depth as you're increasing the counter depth.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already have standard countertop depth of 24 inches now.

And you want to use some **not disclosed depth**.

The plywood (or particle board) on top has to be replaced to match the new depth and support the new countertop depth.

Yes, you could move the cabinets, and the dishwasher to the new location without problems.

As for the sink and the faucets, it is up to you how you want it to look like. If you move the sink you need to redo the plumbing under it, the faucets do not care about the location.